# Sending emails in angular js using yii2 rest api

Tags: php, angularjs, email, yii2

I have been using [githubjeka Yii2 rest api](https://github.com/githubjeka/angular-yii2) to manage rest api calls from angular JS to yii2 framework.

Could anyone suggest on swiftmailer that is how I can send a mail from the angular JS frontend application to using yii2 as the  backend to manage the sending of the mail.

Comment: What is the problem? Make request from angular to your backend and send mail there? Documentation for swiftmailer is ok. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html First write code and then ask if something not working.